# How to solve the shell script, the function returns to cause an exception exit

Tags: linux, shell

I have a requirement to determine if a file exists to determine if other operations are needed, but I found through the following shell script that it does not go to the if condition when the file does not exist

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
#set -v
#set -x

# set values
readonly TRUE=0
readonly FALSE=1


# return $TRUE (0) if file found
# return $FALSE (1) if file not found
is_file_found() {
    [ -f "$1" ] &&  return $TRUE || return $FALSE
}

test() {
    filepath="notexist.txt"
    # filepath="exist.txt"   # Using it will output the normal
    is_file_found ${filepath}
    if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
        echo "${filepath} not found."
    fi
    echo "${filepath} found."
}

main() {

    case "$1" in
    "test")
        test "$2"
        ;;
    esac
}
main "$@"
```

using the -x parameter it seems to exit directly when the function returns.

```bash
# sh -x  test.sh test
+ set -e
+ readonly TRUE=0
+ TRUE=0
+ readonly FALSE=1
+ FALSE=1
+ main test
+ case "$1" in
+ test ''
+ filepath=notexist.txt
+ is_file_found notexist.txt
+ '[' -f notexist.txt ']'
+ return 1
```

For existing files, the output is judged to be correct, and the output is as follows

```
# sh -x  test.sh test
+ set -e
+ readonly TRUE=0
+ TRUE=0
+ readonly FALSE=1
+ FALSE=1
+ main test
+ case "$1" in
+ test ''
+ filepath=exist.txt
+ is_file_found exist.txt
+ '[' -f exist.txt ']'
+ return 0
+ '[' 0 -eq 1 ']'
+ echo 'exist.txt found.'
exist.txt found.
```

what is the cause of this and how can I fix it? I really appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 0):

comment out this line `set -e`, and it will work.

> -e: Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status.

see also: [set man page](https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/seth.html)